# Why does my SQL return unwanted records with my OR in Where clause

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Lets say I have this table called subscriptions on Redshift (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c6c53/1):

```
    id  | subscription_type | subscription_origin
-------------------------------------------------
    100 | monthly           | trial_page
    101 | annual_trial      | sales_rep
    102 | monthly           | sales_rep
    103 | annual            | sales_rep
```

returning all rows without 'trial' in subscription type looks right:

```
select * from subscriptions where subscription_type NOT LIKE '%trial%'
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c6c53/2
```

but I want to return all rows that don't have 'trial' in **either** the subscription_type or subscription_origin.

So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE subscription_type NOT LIKE '%trial%' OR
subscription_origin NOT LIKE '%trial_page%'
```

but http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c6c53/3 returns all the rows.

how do I exclude all the rows with trial present in the string?

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? "I want to avoid all of the 'trial' subscriptions. If I filter out the ones where the _type_ is 'trial' I still get ones entered on the 'trial page'. ..."

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `AND`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE subscription_type NOT LIKE '%trial%' 
  AND subscription_origin NOT LIKE '%trial_page%';
```

**[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c6c53/6/0)**

This is the example when knowledge of boolean algebra is useful:

> [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):
>
> The rules can be expressed in English as:
>
> - the negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations; and
> - the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations;

Let's assume you want to find strings that are `col1 LIKE A OR col2 LIKE B`:

```
-- assuming that both columns are not nullable
NOT(col1 LIKE A OR col2 LIKE B) <=> col1 NOT LIKE A AND col2 NOT LIKE B
```